# Excel VBA copy creates new worksheet instead of copying to existing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with a macro button that opens a file dialog. I select a second unopened workbook to open and want to copy the contents from the worksheet into an existing worksheet in the workbook I run the macro from.

This works except that instead copying the contents into the target worksheet it creates a new one. The code in question:

```
'clear contents and then copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target Sheet").Cells.ClearContents
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target Sheet")
```

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried variants that do not work at all such as:

```
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target Sheet")
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target Sheet").Range("A1")
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target Sheet").Range("A1")
```

Comment: Doing `Sheets().Copy` copies the Worksheet. You likely want something like `WB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target Sheet").Range("A1")`  (Off the top of my head, I can't remember if you need the destination to have `.Range("A1")`, or perhaps just `.Cells`)

Comment: That was my hope but these variants don't work as far as I can tell. I tried `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target Sheet").Cells and the other variations you implied

Comment: Nevermind, I had a typo in the last effort. Changing the original to ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target Sheet").Cells worked

Answer (score 1):

it might be the reason that you are copying the complete sheet instead of the contents of the source sheet.
I have tested the following code to copy the contents of sheet1 for my existing workbook and pasting it into a new workbook:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

It worked perfectly.

Or if you have the destination file open, then you can try the following:

```
Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook
Dim Ws1, Ws2 As Worksheet
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set Ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Test1.xlsx")
Set Ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

Ws1.Cells.Copy
Ws2.Activate
Ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End Sub
```

Last code is a bit elaborative but serves the purpose

Comment: I'd recommend against using `.Activate`, it won't really affect the code since you qualified the ranges, but just making a broad comment here.